# Width percentages won't align together (nav menu with web content)

Tags: html, css, width, navigationbar

I have a problem with aligning a navigation menu with the rest of the content of my website.

Both are in 80% but when I see them in a larger screen size it won't align... even if I reduce the size of the navigator. Do I have to put it inside a new div or something?

Here is the css for the **navigation menu**:

```css
#navigation {
width: 100%;    
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;

#navigation ul {
width: 80%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
padding: 0;
```

Here is the css for the **rest of the content**:

```css
#container {
width: 80%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

The website is: http://josefinaechenique.esy.es/biografia.html

**photo of the problem**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F67h.png)

Same is happening with my `#fixedbar`. If you can help me with that too it would be amazing. I'm new here.

Comment: if you simply remove the width on "#container" then it should line up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the margin from container

```
#container{width:90%;}
```